# compute the double integral of $4x$ from $y = x^2-1$ to $ y=x+1$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

compute the double integral of $4x$ from $y = x^2-1$ to $y=x+1$

I just got done doing this on a test but after tripple checking it it kept coming out as -15, and I was sure that the function that was at the top of the enclosed area in the graph goes on the upper bound, $x+1$, and the other at the lower bound. And I saw that the points intercepted at $x= -1$ and $x = 2$ so I made those the lower and upper bounds, respectively on my outer integral. Can someone tell me if I did it right(if the answer is 15) and why the answer kept coming out negative?

Comment: Are you trying to calculate $$\int_{-1}^2\int_{x^2-1}^{x+1}4x\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$$ ?

Comment: I believe so, but the question didn't show the integral setup like that. we had to figure that part out ourselves.

Comment: it just had $SS4xdA$ and gave us the two functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
I&=\int_{-1}^2\int_{x^2-1}^{x+1}4x\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx
\\
&=\int_{-1}^24x(x+1-(x^2-1))\,\mathrm dx
\\
&=\int_{-1}^24x(x+1)(2-x)\,\mathrm dx
\\
&=\int_{-1}^2-4x^3+4x^2+8x\,\mathrm dx
\\
&=\left[-x^4+\frac43x^3+4x^2\right]_{-1}^2
\\
&=-16+\frac{32}3+16+1+\frac43-4
\\
&=12+1-4
\\
I&=9\end{align}$$

Seems like the answer is neither $+15$ nor $-15$.

Comment: dangit, I factored out a -4 first for some reason and it kept coming out that way.

Comment: It is very easy to lose minus signs in integrals, you could end up having some limits the wrong way round, or forget to carry certain minus signs through brackets. In any case, I wouldn't worry about that too much, just try to get the method right - it looks like you did! :)